# Can't use newly imported components in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, import, components

I've been working on this program and I've recently tried to use some new components from the react-native library like `Icon` and `Header` but whenever I try to use them in the render function I get error:

**"Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."**

This is really weird to me because I was, and still am, using components like `Image`, `Text`, and `View` without a problem so I don't get why I would be having an issue now with these new components. I'm not sure what I changed in my program to cause something like this to happen.

Only thing I can think of is that "Settings" used to be a default class but it is now not, but that doesn't explain how the old component I was using from the library still work.   Keep in mind the other components I imported before like `Image` and others still work.

Here's and snippet of the offending code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,  Text, View,  TouchableHighlight,  Image, Header, Icon} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export class Settings extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{height: 55,  backgroundColor: '#007ebc'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: "row", marginLeft: 10}}>
           <Icon //<-------USING ICON WILL GIVE ME ERROR
             name = 'arrowleft' 
           />             
           <Image source={require("../assets/LogoLrg.png")} 
            style={{ width: 55, height: 30, marginTop: 10 }}   
            />
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>   Settings </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Try it by  changing like this - import createStackNavigator  from 'react-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have missed some major update to React Native, you cannot import `Header` and `Icon` components from `react-native` because they don't exist. These components may be a part of some open-source library like `react-native-elements` or `native-base`, so you first have to install them:

```
npm i native-base --save
```

or,

```
npm i react-native-elements --save
```

and then use them:

```
import { Header, Icon } from 'react-native-elements' //or 'native-base'
```

RN Elements: [`Icon`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/icon.html), [`Header`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/header.html)

Native Base: [`Icon`](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#icon-def-headref), [`Header`](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `Icon` or `Header` component exists in react-native library.

You can check it in react native website or `react-native.js` source code.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started